# Typescript not working in visual studio 2015

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I don't know what's wrong. Currently, the typescript file doesn't display correctly in Visual Studio 2015. See attached image.
[image]

Comment: Did you recently update the TypeScript-Version and/or the Visual Studio-Version? Also are there any errors in the 'Output' window?

Comment: I installed the Typescript 2.0 at first. After that, I uninstalled the Typescript 2.0. After I get this all white fonts issue, I reinstalled the Typescript 1.8.4. Still it's not working. Didn't see any errors in 'Output' window.

Comment: There's already an open issue regarding that problem (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11110). Deleting `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache` and then running `devenv /setup` as admin fixed it for me though. (As described in the comment from `paulvanbrenk` here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7519)

Comment: @Philipp: Thanks. It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already an open issue regarding that problem (http://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11110).

A possible fix (as this might be some kind of caching issue) is to delete

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCac‌​he
```

and the run `devenv /setup` as admin.

Detailed Information can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7519 (Comment from `paulvanbrenk`)